# Read excel files with first few letters of its name

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have 4 excel files saved in a directory as such:

Data_1_ABC.xlsx  created at 6 hrs

Data_2_XYD.xlsx  created at 7 hrs

Data_3_DEF.xlsx  created at 8 hrs

Data_4_KLM.xlsx  created at 9 hrs

In order to read the latest csv file, I have used following codes:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
  
all_files = glob.glob('Data_*.xlsx') 

Select_latest_file = max(all_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print("\n","File selected is: ",Select_latest_file,"\n")
df  = pd.read_excel(Select_latest_file)
print(df)
```

Now, latest file selected is Data_4_KLM.csv which is perfectly fine.

However, the files keep repeating after regular intervals and the letters after **Data_4_** i.e. **KLM** keep changing.

So, I wish to extract the contents of the file provided that the csv file starts with **Data_4_**

I tried following codes, but could not get any results:

```
if Select_latest_file == glob.glob('Data_4_*.xlsx'):
    print("Data_4 has been has been selected")
```

Can somebody please let me know how do we go about doing this ?

Comment: What does it mean "created at 6 hours" ? Can you please clarify that.

Comment: It is like in 6am. (24hrs clock cycle)

Comment: I believe the glob.glob function returns a list of files matching your criteria. Therefore, in your second approach, once you have selected all files matching your criteria ```Select_latest_file == glob.glob('Data_4_*.xlsx')``` , you then need to identify the file in the list with latest information.  Assuming the identifiers are the three letter codes and they follow a similar pattern to what is shown, You should be able to sort Select_latest_file and then use select_latest_file[-1] to get the last one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @itprorh66 for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

[glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which
> must be a string containing a path specification

Therefore, `Select_latest_file == glob.glob('Data_4_*.xlsx')` will fail as you are comparing a `str` to a `list`.

Consider this example:

```py
from glob import glob

p1 = "hi_*"
p2 = "*_there"
p3 = "*_here"
p4 = "missing"

print(glob(p1))
print(glob(p2))
print(glob(p3))
print(glob(p4))

for filename in glob(p1):
    print(filename)
```

Output:

```
['hi_there', 'hi_here']
['hi_there']
['hi_here']
[]
hi_there
hi_here
```

However, in your case you could simply `if Select_latest_file.startswith("Data_4")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kacper for your valuable suggestions

Comment: @RanjanPal I've suggested a simpler approach right now as well (see latest edit)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kacper  for your valuable feedback. The (see latest edit) part is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood so far is "all_files" is a list and "Select_latest_file" is a string.

Hence we can extract the first 7 letters of the string and then extract **Data_4_** file as such:

```
First_7_letters_of_file = Select_latest_file[:7]

if First_7_letters_of_file == 'Data_4_':
    print("Data-4 has been selected")
```